# How would I debug this to write webscraped content to CSV under field names? (Python, BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm hoping for help in debugging this script. When I am simply printing out the iterative loop I don't have any issues. How would I now write that content to a csv file under the proper field names? Script is below

'''

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv, requests, re

# The following code is used to set the pythonssl default cipher list - needed if the server has an outdated openssl
try:
    requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.DEFAULT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST += 'HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'
except AttributeError:
    # no pyopenssl support used / needed / available
    pass
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += 'HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'

# Set HTML headers to emulate Firefox browser to avoid bot security
# Potentially unused, but good practice to enable proper script function
html_headers = {    
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
    }


# Download BMO branch entries
base_url = "https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/{}/Bmo+Banque+De+Montr%C3%A9al/Canada" # URL structure of entries
first_page_request = requests.get(base_url.format("1"), headers=html_headers)   # Format method used to insert page number into greater URL
first_page_content = BeautifulSoup(first_page_request.content, "html.parser")   # Grabs all page content using Beautiful Soup module and standard Python parser

# Get total HTML page count for BMO entries
page_count_class = first_page_content.find_all(class_="pageCount")[0] 
total_pages = re.search("([0-9]+)</span>", str(page_count_class)).group(1)  # Extract the last page number from the total page count at the bottom of the page

# Initial CSV handling
f = open("bmo_data.csv", "w", newline="")    # Chose w mode to write to a file
field_names = ["name", "street_address", "city", "province", "postal_code"]
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=field_names)   # Setting the writer and field names
writer.writeheader()

# Running iterative loop through each page of the yellowpages listings for BMO
for page in range(1, int(total_pages) + 1):
    page_request = requests.get(base_url.format(page), headers=html_headers)
    page_html_content = BeautifulSoup(page_request.content, "html.parser")

    entry_names = page_html_content.find_all(class_="jsListingName")    # Get store name
    entry_addresses = page_html_content.find_all("span", itemprop="streetAddress")  # Get street address HTML object
    entry_cities = page_html_content.find_all("span", itemprop="addressLocality")   # Get city HTML object
    entry_provinces = page_html_content.find_all("span", itemprop="addressRegion")  # Get province HTML object
    entry_postal = page_html_content.find_all("span", itemprop="postalCode")    # Get postal code HTML object

    for name, address, city, province, postalCode in zip(entry_names, entry_addresses, entry_cities, entry_provinces, entry_postal):
        writer.writerow(page, name.get_text(), address.get_text(), city.get_text(), province.get_text(), postalCode.get_text())

f.close()
```

'''

Comment: Hi! Have you read the CSV documentation? I'd check out the [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), put your data into a list of dictionaries. For each dictionary in the list, the keys are column names. The example at that link shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your approach is that if an element is missing, all the lists will be out of sync when you try and write them. A better approach is to find an HTML element that encompasses one result and then just get the elements for just the one entry. This can then be written a row at time.

As some items are not always present, you can use a function to return a blank string for when the `.find()` failed to locate a suitable value.

For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv, requests, re


def get_text(soup):
    ''' Return the text if available else an empty string '''
    return soup.get_text(strip=True) if soup else ''
    
    
# The following code is used to set the pythonssl default cipher list - needed if the server has an outdated openssl
try:
    requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.DEFAULT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST += 'HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'
except AttributeError:
    # no pyopenssl support used / needed / available
    pass
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += 'HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'

# Set HTML headers to emulate Firefox browser to avoid bot security
# Potentially unused, but good practice to enable proper script function
html_headers = {    
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
    }


# Download BMO branch entries
base_url = "https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/{}/Bmo+Banque+De+Montr%C3%A9al/Canada" # URL structure of entries
first_page_request = requests.get(base_url.format("1"), headers=html_headers)   # Format method used to insert page number into greater URL
first_page_content = BeautifulSoup(first_page_request.content, "html.parser")   # Grabs all page content using Beautiful Soup module and standard Python parser

# Get total HTML page count for BMO entries
page_count_class = first_page_content.find_all(class_="pageCount")[0] 
total_pages = re.search("([0-9]+)</span>", str(page_count_class)).group(1)  # Extract the last page number from the total page count at the bottom of the page

# Initial CSV handling

with open("bmo_data.csv", "w", encoding="latin-1", newline="") as f_output:   # Chose w mode to write to a file
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)   # Setting the writer
    csv_output.writerow(["name", "street_address", "city", "province", "postal_code"])

    # Running iterative loop through each page of the yellowpages listings for BMO
    for page in range(1, int(total_pages) + 1):
        print(f"Getting page {page} of {int(total_pages)}")
        page_request = requests.get(base_url.format(page), headers=html_headers)
        page_html_content = BeautifulSoup(page_request.content, "html.parser")

        for div in page_html_content.find_all('div', class_="listing_right_section"):
            entry_name = div.find(class_="jsListingName")    # Get store name
            entry_address = div.find("span", itemprop="streetAddress")   # Get street address HTML object
            entry_city = div.find("span", itemprop="addressLocality")   # Get city HTML object
            entry_province = div.find("span", itemprop="addressRegion")  # Get province HTML object
            entry_postal = div.find("span", itemprop="postalCode")    # Get postal code HTML object
            
            csv_output.writerow([
                get_text(entry_name), 
                get_text(entry_address), 
                get_text(entry_city), 
                get_text(entry_province), 
                get_text(entry_postal)])
```

If the fieldnames are fixed, you don't need to use `DictWriter()`, that is up to you though.

This would give output starting:

```
name,street_address,city,province,postal_code
BMO Bank of Montreal,270 Dundas St,London,ON,N6A 1H3
BMO Banque De Montréal,51 Notre Dame E Victorvl,Victoriaville,QC,G6P 1R6
BMO Banque De Montréal,739 Rue Conseil Sher,,QC,
```